# Remove punctuation from characters in C

Tags: c

I have a text file called `adc.txt`, and I'm trying to read the characters and remove all punctuation inside.

The file `adc.text`:

```
*1. g7 h(8) zs89';
2. ;';fd(sa
```

The actual result was:

```
ghzsfdsa
```

What I expected was:

```
g7 h 8 zs89 fd sa
```

Any suggestion?

Here's my code:

```
void chip_punct(char *ch){
    for(char *p = ch; *p; ++p)
        if(isalpha(*p))
            *ch++ = *p;
    *ch = '\0';
}

int main(void){
    FILE *fp;
    char ch[1024];
    size_t pos =0;

    fp = fopen("adc.txt", "r");
    if(fp != NULL){
        while(!feof(fp)){
            fgets(ch, sizeof(ch), fp);
            chip_punct(ch);
            printf("%s", ch);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could have an `else *ch++ = ' ';` Also please see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: You're only leaving characters where `isalpha` returns true. So it will remove numbers and spaces as well.

Comment: Ah, I just noticed... `isalnum()` is what you need. But if you want consecutive non-alphanum characters replaced with a **single** space, you'll need another variable to keep track of that.

Comment: Why doesn't the expected result include `1` and `2` from the beginning of each line? Are those not really part of the file?

Comment: Your expected output is inserting a space for the first '(' but not for the closing ')'?

Comment: @MichaelBianconi it appears that a **single** space is required for any number of consecutive non-alphanum characters. There is only one space before the `'f'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your `chip_punct` function to give the desired result.

1. I call `isalnum` to check for alphanumeric - letters and numbers. `isalpha` checks only for letters.
2. I use a flag `addSpace` to remember if last char was not a alphanumeric. Then, before adding a char, I check if a space needs to be added.
3. I remember the first `ch` position with `ch0` to avoid adding a space at the beginning.

```
void chip_punct(char *ch) {
    int addSpace = 0; // Flag if need to add space
    char *ch0 = ch; // Remember first position
    for (char *p = ch; *p; ++p)
    {
        if (isalnum(*p)) // Check if char is alphanumeric
        {
            if (addSpace && ch > ch0) // Check if need to add space
                *ch++ = ' ';
            *ch++ = *p;
            addSpace = 0;
        }
        else
            addSpace = 1;
    }
    *ch = '\0';
}
```

Output:

```
1 g7 h 8 zs892 fd sa
```

The lack of a space between `zs89` and `2` from the next line is because the `main` prints them with no space. You can change that by adding a space: `printf("%s ", ch);`

Answer (score -1):

You're shifting elements left when you reach a symbol. Try replacing symbols with `' '`.

Comment: Replacing symbols with space characters would not produce the expected output the OP presented.